# How can I clear a write("message")

Tags: message, code.org

Basically, I have a button that write("message"+myVar).
Then I want to press a button that will delete the written message, but not mess with the variable at all.

I am very new to coding. I code on Code.org which is powered by javascript.

Much thanks

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Always try to share your code so anyone can help you better. As much as I understand there are lots of ways to achieve this. The most straightforward one could be to create a `textLabel` with an empty string and then modify it with the `setText` property of code.org. Like so;

```
var myVar = "something";
textLabel("messageId","");
  
button("createButton", "create");
onEvent("createButton", "click", function( ) {
  setText("messageId", "message" + myVar);
});

button("deleteButton", "delete");
onEvent("deleteButton", "click", function( ) {
  setText("messageId",myVar);
});
```